# How can I send character to usb port?

Tags: javascript, ascii

Is there any way to send ASCII symbol/character to USB via webpage (HTML)?

We have a local PC with a webpage running in kiosk mode. The webpage have a button that should send that symbol/character to USB. How it can be done?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your webpage hosted on localhost using nodejs or wamp or something like that by any chance?

Comment: Yes, we have wamp

Comment: Then you should make the button make a request to wamp that will do that for you (in backend). I don't know how to do it in wamp but I think it's doable. Edit the question to show that, or just ask a new one focusing on wamp more.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Code running in web pages is sandboxed and has no direct hardware access in general and definitely no direct USB access.

Comment: or not: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web

Answer (score 2):

It may actually be possible, though only by using an experimental feature that's only available in some browsers.

More specifically, there exists a draft specification of the [WebUSB API](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/) which aims to give access to USB devices from the browser, albeit with some limitations for security reasons. For instance, Chrome requires the page to be served over HTTPS.

This feature is currently implemented in newer versions of Chrome and, according to MDN, Opera.

There is some more information about it on [Google's blog](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web).

Answer (score 0):

Question is:

> Is there any way to send ASCII symbol/character to USB via webpage
>   (HTML)?

I don't know if [Electron Apps](https://electronjs.org/apps) is what you call a webpage, but it is to me. If Electron App enters your usecase, you can access the NodeJS API, and therefore your machine.

This could be the answer you are looking for, if the only limitation you have for your question is the use of web languages (HTML, CSS, Javascript). If your limitation is give access to the world through a classic web browser, as @Quentin sayed in his answer, it is not possible.

**Thanks god it's not possible.**